# Freezing with nvidia-drm modeset=1

Tags: linux, arch-linux, nvidia, drm, kms

#### Setup

I have an Optimus laptop with a GTX 1050, Intel i7 7700HQ, a 128GB SSD and 8GB of RAM. Using Arch Linux and KDE Plasma.

[image: Neofetch]

Using Nvidia proprietary drivers version 396.24-19.

```
$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.11.
KDE Frameworks: 5.48.0
kf5-config: 1.0

$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.13.3

$ uname -r
4.17.9-1-ARCH
```

I had tearing with the proprietary Nvidia drivers, and enabling DRM KMS seemed to fix it. I did it [this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1024499/852424).

Sadly, I came across a couple of problems after this:

#### Problems

- Resizing windows by dragging them to one of the edges of the screen sometimes freezes the window in place for about 20 seconds. I can only move my mouse, change to another tty, numlock and capslock still work. There are no logs in `journalctl -b` when this happens.
- There are also random freezes, where NOTHING responds. I can't use my mouse or my keyboard, even numlock and capslock don't work. When looking in the `journalctl` log, I can always see these errors:

  ```
  ArchLinux kernel: nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-c07c20bb-45d1-9ef7-5dec-2ccd17eb1af2) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
  ArchLinux kernel: nvidia-modeset: Freed GPU:0 (GPU-c07c20bb-45d1-9ef7-5dec-2ccd17eb1af2) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
  ```

So how do I fix these problems? What other logs do I need to provide?

---

**Edit**: all my issues have gone away since I changed from KDE Plasma with KWin to bspwm with compton. Nvidia KMS works without freezes.